# What's a more Pythonic way of grabbing N items from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

In Python, suppose I want to grab N arbitrary items from a dictionary—say, to print them, to inspect a few items. I don't care which items I get. I don't want to turn the dictionary into a list (as does some code I have seen); that seems like a waste. I can do it with the following code (where N = 5), but it seems like there has to be a more Pythonic way:

```py
count = 0
for item in my_dict.items():
    if count >= 5:
        break
    print(item)
    count += 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what's wrong with this code? That actually looks like a good and Pythonic way already.

Comment: I guess it's the use of a counter, which seems more typical of C/C++, at least from what I understand. But I'm new to Python, so what do I know? I just thought there might be something more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to slice any iterable (not only lists):

```python
>>> import itertools
>>> my_dict = {i: i for i in range(10)}
>>> list(itertools.islice(my_dict.items(), 5))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

Comment: For my use case, I would loop over the slice: `for item in itertools.islice(my_dict.items(), 5): print(item)`

Comment: That makes sense. I used the `list()` to be able to print a representation of the resulting generator, it is not required in general.

Answer (score 1):

I might use `zip` and `range`:

```
>>> my_dict = {i: i for i in range(10)}
>>> for _, item in zip(range(5), my_dict.items()):
...     print(item)
...
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(4, 4)
```

The only purpose of the `range` here is to give an iterable that will cause `zip` to stop after 5 iterations.

Comment: Interesting! A little hard for me to read as a beginner/intermediate learner.

Comment: @bhagerty The trick is the fact that `zip` truncates the result to the length of the shortest iterator. That's why this solution either returns 5 or less elements depending on the size of `my_dict`.

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk! Makes sense why it works. Still, since "Readability counts" (PEP 20), I wanted to point out that I found it hard to read. I think the `itertools` solution is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify what you have slightly:

```
for count, item in enumerate(dict.items()):
    if count >= 5:
        break
    print(item)
```

Note:  in this case when you're looping through .items(), you're getting a key/value pair, which can be unpacked as you iterate:

```
for count, (key, value) in enumerate(dict.items()):
    if count >= 5:
        break
    print(f"{key=} {value=})
```

If you want just the keys, you can just iterate over the dict.

```
for count, key in enumerate(dict):
    if count >= 5:
        break
    print(f"{key=})
```

If you want just the values:

```
for count, value in enumerate(dict.values()):
    if count >= 5:
        break
    print(f"{value=})
```

And last note:  using `dict` as a variable name overwrites the built in `dict` and makes it unavailable in your code.

Comment: Definitely an improvement, and `enumerate` is more pythonic. Still not sure about using "count," though. Also, thanks for the point about `dict`. I revised the question to not use it (I didn't use it in practice; it was just a sloppy attempt to generalize my question).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I would like to use slice notation to do this, but `dict.items()` returns an *iterator*, which is not slicable.

You have two main options:

1. Make it something that slice notation works on:

```
x = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
for item, index in list(x.items())[:5]:
  print(item)
```

2. Use something that works on iterators. In this case, the built-in (and exceedingly popular) itertools package:

```
import itertools
x = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
for item in itertools.islice(x.items(), 5):
  print(item)
```

Comment: The first way is worse than the O.P.'s code because it creates an unnecessary list copying the entire dictionary. And "item, index" are bad variable names for the key and values in the dict.  The islice is fine, but it was already mentioned in an earlier answer.

Comment: Thanks! Solution 1, using a list, is something I've seen and tried to rule out in my question. I'm pretty sure that converts the whole dictionary into a list, just so I can get a few items from the list. But Solution 2 is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, I realize now that Solution 2 doesn't quite work, because it only slices the keys, whereas I wanted the keys and values.  I need `for item in itertools.islice(my_dict.items(), 5):` etc.